# Django-guardian on DB with shared (non-exclusive) access

Tags: python, django, database-permissions, django-permissions

I am developing a Django app being a Web frontend to some Oracle database with another local DB keeping app's data such as Guardian permissions. The problem is that it can be modified from different places that I don't have control of.

Let's say we have 3 models: `User`, `Thesis` and `UserThesis`.

`UserThesis` - a table specifying relationship between `Thesis` and `User` (`User` being co-author of `Thesis`)

Scenario:

1. `User` is removed as an author of `Thesis` by removing entry in `UserThesis` table by some other app.
2. `User` tries to modify `Thesis` using our Django app. And he succeeds, because Guardian and Django do not know about change in `UserThesis`.

I thought about some solutions:

1. Having some cron job look for changes in `UserThesis` by checking the modification date of entry. Easy to check for additions, removals would require looking on all relationships again.
2. Modifying Oracle DB schema to add Guardian DB tables and creating triggers on `UserThesis` table. I wouldn't like to do this, because of Oracle DB being shared among number of different apps.
3. Manually checking for relationship in views and templates (heavier load on Oracle).

Which one is the best? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with manually checking the permissions, caching it whenever I can. I ended up with get_perms_from_cache(self, user) model method which helps me a lot.